# Can I normalize cosine-similarities?

Tags: percentage, normalize, cosine-similarity

Is there a way to convert a list of cosine similarities to percentage? I tried to wrap my brain around this but I'm in great doubt.

Would it make sense to normalize the cosine values of the four documents like so:

```
Doc #1  0.9600
Doc #2  0.9300
Doc #3  0.8800
Doc #4  0.8500
```

Summing them all up

```
0.9600 + 0.9300 + 0.8800 + 0.8500 = 3.6200
```

And normalize them.

```
Doc #1  0.9600 / 3.6200 = 0.2652
Doc #2  0.9300 / 3.6200 = 0.2570
Doc #3  0.8800 / 3.6200 = 0.2431
Doc #4  0.8500 / 3.6200 = 0.2348
```

or is there are more accepted way of displaying this?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on your use case, but in general I don't think there's much of a need to normalize cosine similarity scores as they are already on a 0 to 1 scale.